# Quota settings on Folder Level

Tags: linux, quota, directory

I have requirement to enforce quota settings at folder level. And this enforcement is purely based on folders and not on groups.

So I may have to monitor a folder /dev1/folder1 and its subfolder /dev1/folder1/folder1_2 separately.

And I think quota package in linux purely works on groups or users at file system level.

Creating a group for each folder to monitor may solve this issue, but it increases the complexity for management of user or group permissions.

Do I have any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use LVM(http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) or:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/file_fs1 count=20 bs=1M
mke2fs -F /tmp/file_fs1
mkdir -p /dev1/folder1
mount -o loop /tmp/file_fs1 /dev1/folder1

dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/file_fs2 count=10 bs=1M
mke2fs -F /tmp/file_fs2
mkdir /dev1/folder1/folder1_2
mount -o loop /tmp/file_fs2 /dev1/folder1/folder1_2
```

df -h:

```
/dev/loop0             20M  173K   19M   1% /dev1/folder1
/dev/loop1            9,7M   92K  9,1M   1% /dev1/folder1/folder1_2
```

Comment: @binddn But one trickey requirement is folder1 size  should include its contents and folder1_2 size. And limit for folder1 includes contents in folder1_2